# Geo Spacial Bounding Box Rectangle Calculation Error: Latitude Incorrect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, geolocation, gps

Can any trig or GPS experts help me out here? I'm trying to create a geo-spacial bounding box (rectangle) calculation returning the maximum latitude and longitude using the following method that I've retrieved. I am calling the method once for each of the for bearings: north, south, east and west. With these four values I intend to query my Core Data store for all objects within the box.

```
  -(CLLocation*) offsetLocation:(CLLocation*)startLocation:(double)offsetMeters:(double)bearing {


    double EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_METERS = 6372796.99;
    double newLatitude = asin( sin(startLocation.coordinate.latitude) * cos(offsetMeters/EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_METERS) + cos(startLocation.coordinate.latitude) * sin(offsetMeters/EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_METERS) * cos(bearing) );
    double newLongitude = startLocation.coordinate.longitude + atan2( sin(bearing) * sin(offsetMeters/EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_METERS) * cos(startLocation.coordinate.latitude), cos(offsetMeters/EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS_METERS) - sin(startLocation.coordinate.latitude) * sin(newLatitude));


    CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLatitude longitude:newLongitude];
    [tempLocation autorelease];
    return tempLocation;
}
```

The problem is the calculation for the newLatitude offset is definitely incorrect. Given the following:

startLocation: latitude 37.331688999999997, longitude -122.030731
  offsetMeters  : 1000
  bearing       : 0 (north)

newLatitude returns -0.36726592610659514 (incorrect).

Any suggestions? I've coded around this particular formula until now and this one has me stumped. I've also tried translating a different formula from PHP to no avail. I figure the above is exactly what I need if it can be tweaked.

Thanks,
b.dot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code, but you could also use the MapKit function `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance()` to have the framework calculate a bounding box for you.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = { 37.3, -122.0 };
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 2000.0, 2000.0);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWestCorner, southEastCorner;
northWestCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
northWestCorner.longitude = center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
southEastCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
southEastCorner.longitude = center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
```

Comment: Wow. I'm not using MapKit, so I hadn't thought of looking there. Thanks. I'm going to try both methods.

Comment: MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance makes a nice box very easily, however I'm not sure how to retrieve the bounds (maximum latitude or longitude) of the newly created region. All of the properties seemed to be related to the MapView itself.

Comment: It's just a little math, isn't it? I added some code to my answer. Note that this code doesn't work if the bounding box crosses the date line or the poles. But then, you'd need to split it into multiple boxes anyway to query the data store.

Comment: Ole, Thanks!.

It works perfectly. This was my first experience with MapKit and it never occurred to me that you could do this with simple math. I spent two days trying to understand the Haversine and Vincenty formulas until my brain was mush. Now, that is "a little math". :)

Answer (score 1):

CLLocationCoordinate2D stores coordinates in degrees, but the trig functions you're using require radian units.  If you convert to radians (multiply by M_PI/180, or 0.017453293f), it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

How are you guys setting up the NSPredicates?

I seem to run into performance issues with mine.

```
NSPredicate *northWestLat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY locations.lat > %lf", northWestCorner.latitude];
NSPredicate *southhWestLat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY locations.lat < %lf", southEastCorner.latitude];
NSPredicate *latitudePredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:northWestLat, southhWestLat, nil]];

NSPredicate *northWestLng = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY locations.lng < %lf", northWestCorner.longitude];
NSPredicate *southEastLng = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY locations.lng > %lf", southEastCorner.longitude];
NSPredicate *longitudePredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:northWestLng, southEastLng, nil]];

NSPredicate *coordPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:latitudePredicate, longitudePredicate, nil]];
```

Comment: Why are you using any?  Why not just `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude > %f AND latitude < %f AND longitude > %f AND longitude < %f", latMin, latMax, lngMin, lngMax];`