# Get Bounding Box from lat/long and distance

Tags: objective-c, ios7, twitter, mapkit, geocoding

Im using twitter stream api for my ios project. Stream API has a [location](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations) parameter. How can i get bounding box coordinates from user location(lat/long) and 1km distance ? Is there any API or tool in MapKit or mathematical functions ?

Input

```
(latitude = 37.785834, longitude = -122.406417)
Distance = 1000 meter
```

Output

```
latMin: 37.789934 longMin : -122.416417
latMax: 37.787834  longMax : -122.396417
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the bounding box for a given lat/lng location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2409582/467105.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, check out the functions in `<MapKit/MKGeometry.h>` like `MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude()`, which will allow you to convert distance to map points, then map points to screen points.

Comment: Actually i don't want convert anything to map points. Just need boundary coordinates from user location. I've added example for clarity.