# Center coordinate with radius convert to ne and sw coordinates

Tags: ios, cllocationdistance, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and some radius in meters. 
I would like to get two bounding coordinates (top-right and bottom-left) of the area.

Comment: The trigonometry in the linked answer might be unnecessary for your case.  [This approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2409582/467105) might be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to location these 2 red squares:

[image]

Thanks to the code you that can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6634982/2116172) the implementation is pretty simple:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cc0 = coordinate;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cc1 = [self coordinateFromCoord:cc0 atDistanceKm:circleRadius atBearingDegrees:45];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cc2 = [self coordinateFromCoord:cc0 atDistanceKm:circleRadius atBearingDegrees:225];
    NSLog(@"%.5f,%.5f -> %.5f,%.5f AND %.5f, %.5f", cc0.latitude, cc0.longitude, cc1.latitude, cc1.longitude, cc2.latitude, cc2.longitude);
```

Comment: I was looking for the coordinates of the external square, but I think I can figure it out by myself with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand last comment. I think the simplest is to calculate new radius as hypotenuse of the triangle.

Comment: Did you mean to replace ```double distanceRadians = distanceKm / 6371.0;``` from the other post?

Comment: Ah right it is the quickest way to do that. But if you have some time you can just add distance calculated into radians to the center point and adjust toLonRadians to be in the range -180 to +180.

Comment: Anyway I deleted that comment because I paste wrong calculation. Angle = distanceInMeters / 6371000; // Earth radius = 6371km